# Spring Integration : How to guarantee the transaction two more jdbc-outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following pattern
[image: my enterprise integration pattern]

I have two kinds of databases. 
One is a internal database where it saves data from 5 json datas from http inbound gateways.
The Other is a external database where it saves final refiend data from 5 jsons saved tables.

The Process is like the followings.

---

- One Transaction

  ① Each message is saved to each table and return status to the client where it sends data.

---

- Second Transaction

  ② If 5 kinds of datas are completed to receive, it activate one service activator where 
  queries 5 tables and make 3 kinds of refined data that will save in external database.

  ③ The next connected channel type is a publish-subscribe channel.

  ④ There are 3 kinds of subscribe channel to deliver each jdbc-outbound-gateway for saving data to external database.
  (There is a rowmapper process to handle saving multiple rows)

How can I set the transaction for being guaranteed?
Please let me know elaborately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `QueueChannel` somewhere upstream (i.e. before the pub sub channel for tx2) and use a `<transactional/>` poller to start the transaction.

Alternatively, insert a transactional gateway...

```
<int:service-activator ... ref="txGw" />

<int:gateway ... service-interface="TX" />

public interface TX {
    @Transactional
    Message<?> exchange(Message<?> m);
}
```

You'll need `<tx:annotation-driven />` to enable transactions in the second case.