# spring integration: int-jdbc:outbound-gateway commit?

Tags: spring-integration

i am trying to understand how the commit works when we use any insert or update statements with jdbc outbound gateway, sometimes we see the process flags is not updated, any inputs would be really helpful

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="update.gateway"
            request-channel="request.channel" reply-channel="reply.channel"
            data-source="dataSource" request-sql-parameter-source-factory="spelSource"
            update="update table set PROCESS_FLAG=:processFlag where QUEUE_VALUE=:queueValue and
                     JOB_ID=:jobId ">
</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wpap your flow to the `Transaction`?

Assume we have a `<gateway>` in the beginning and you initiate it like:

```
public Bar service(Foo foo) {
    return this.gateway.store(foo);
}
```

So, there is just enough mark that method with `@Transactional`.

From other side `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` has `<request-handler-advice-chain>`. And you can put there `tx:advice`:

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
   <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <tx:advice>
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="*"/>
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>
   </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

Anyway Transaction is required to achieve the correct result of DB `UPDATE`.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419602/spring-integration-how-to-guarantee-the-transaction-two-more-jdbc-outbound-gat/26425520#26425520) for other ways to start the transaction upstream.

Comment: if i use the above snippet will it take care of transcation commit, also i am trying to understand what's the default behavior when i don't see any transactional attributes in outbound gateway

Comment: It depends on your DB vendor. See its documentation: what is the behavior, when you don't use transactions. In most cases DB starts local TX on the first DML clause (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` etc.), but there is no guarenty, when it will be commited/roll backed.