# Transaction boundaries without using pollers

Tags: spring-integration

Our project has the following flow pattern:

```
<input-flow> | <routing-flow> | <output-flow>
```

Where the pipes symbolize the transaction boundaries and all flows are multi threaded using TaskExecutors. In the input-flow, the transaction is started by the message-driven-channel-adapter, but in the routing-flow and output-flow it is currently started by a poller which causes latency.

To avoid the poller latency, I would like to create the transaction boundaries using ExecutorChannels, but the ExecutorChannel does not start a transaction for the flow.

Are there other possibilities to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the latency by reducing the polling interval (even to 0) and increasing the receive timeout (at the expense of tying up a scheduler thread to wait for messages).

For an executor channel, you can insert a transactional gateway in the flow (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419602/spring-integration-how-to-guarantee-the-transaction-two-more-jdbc-outbound-gat/26425520#26425520) for an example, or use AOP to start the transaction on a direct channel `send()` somewhere downstream of the executor.